# P4 Windows command line: getting Workspaces for specific Streams?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to get a list of workspaces on a specific Perforce (my machine) that are made for a specific Stream. I can set the host, but haven't found a way to gather this specific set of info. Does anyone have experience here -- would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 clients -S streamName
```

See `p4 help clients`:

```
    clients -- Display list of clients

    p4 clients [-t] [-u user] [[-e|-E] nameFilter -m max] [-S stream]

        Lists all client workspaces currently defined in the server.

        ...

        The -S stream flag limits output to the client workspaces dedicated
        to the stream.
```